# MySQL query optimization for extremly slow query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, execution-time

I'm a web developer and I'm posting for the first time on SO.

Today I'm asking for your help because I already tried all the possibilities with no luck.

I created a SAAS web application that is used by salesman on the ground, it includes an offline version where users don't need to be connected to use it.

As the database is getting bigger, the queries are taking more and more time to be executed.

Today I'm facing a big issue where the query is leading to a timeout when the user tries to display it's result.

So, here's the dump :

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- 86 rows
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id_t2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  quantite_t2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  ca_t2 decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  date_t2 date NOT NULL,
  import_t2 datetime NOT NULL,
  id_enseigne int(11) NOT NULL,
  id_t3 int(11) NOT NULL,
  annee_t2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  mois_t2 int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- 2012065 rows
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id_t2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  id_t0 bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  id_t4 bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  quantite_t1 int(11) NOT NULL,
  ca_t1 decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  pvc_moyen_t1 float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- 388 rows
CREATE TABLE t4 (
  id_t4 int(11) NOT NULL,
  lib_t4 text NOT NULL,
  libcourt_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ean_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  pcb_t4 int(11) NOT NULL,
  pcb2_t4 int(11) NOT NULL,
  fam_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  gam_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  stat_t4 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  vmh_t4 decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  detail_t4 text NOT NULL,
  ingr_t4 text NOT NULL,
  weight_t4 float NOT NULL,
  lifetime_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  pmc1_t4 float NOT NULL,
  pmc2_t4 float NOT NULL,
  dim_t4 decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  ordre_t4 int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_t4 datetime NOT NULL,
  updated_t4 datetime NOT NULL,
  updated_img_t4 datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- 1 row
CREATE TABLE t3 (
  id_t3 int(11) NOT NULL,
  nom_t3 text NOT NULL,
  stat_t3 int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_t3 datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted_t3 datetime NOT NULL,
  updated_t3 datetime NOT NULL,
  ip_create_t3 text NOT NULL,
  ip_delete_t3 text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE t2
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_t2),
  ADD KEY annee_t2 (annee_t2,mois_t2,date_t2);

ALTER TABLE t1
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_t2,id_t0,id_t4);

ALTER TABLE t4
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_t4,ean_t4),
  ADD KEY ean_t4 (ean_t4),
  ADD KEY id_t4 (id_t4);

ALTER TABLE t3
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_t3);


ALTER TABLE t2
  MODIFY id_t2 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE t4
  MODIFY id_t4 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE t3
  MODIFY id_t3 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

COMMIT;
```

The executed query below takes like 4 min to execute :

```
-- execution time 228 seconds
SELECT SUM(t1.ca_t1) AS ca_t4, SUM(t1.quantite_t1) AS qte_t4,
       t4.fam_t4, t4.gam_t4, t4.lib_t4, t4.ean_t4, t4.id_t4,
       t2.annee_t2, t2.mois_t2, COUNT(t1.id_t0) AS count_mag,
       t3.id_t3, t3.nom_t3
FROM t1 t1
INNER JOIN t2 t2 ON t2.id_t2 = t1.id_t2
LEFT JOIN t3 t3 ON t2.id_t3 = t3.id_t3
INNER JOIN t4 t4 ON t1.id_t4 = t4.ean_t4
WHERE t2.date_t2 BETWEEN "2017-05-01" AND "2019-05-01"
GROUP BY t2.annee_t2, t2.mois_t2, t4.id_t4
ORDER BY ca_t4 DESC;
```

I tried all optimization I know to help me reduce execution time but no success...

The EXPLAIN shows this :

```
id  select_type    table    type      possible_keys    key        key_len    ref            rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE         t2       ALL       PRIMARY          NULL       NULL       NULL           86      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE         t3       eq_ref    PRIMARY          PRIMARY    4          db.t2.id_t3    1       
1   SIMPLE         t1       ref       PRIMARY,id_t2    PRIMARY    4          db.t2.id_t2    11266   
1   SIMPLE         t4       ALL       ean_t4           NULL       NULL       NULL           388     Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Can you put an index on the field t2.date_t2 ? And another on t4.ean_t4?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, my bad, the date_t2 was already indexed, my dump wasn't up  to date. I just edited the Q.
Btw, ean_t4 is already indexed.

Comment: Is annee_t2 the year from the date field? If so maybe worth a covering index on annee_t2 and date_t2?

Comment: @Kickstart, yes annee_t2 is the YEAR(date_t2), it's filled in the INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a fairly complex query, with multiple places that will slow it down. However, the first thing I notice is that a double lookup would have to occur in order to use the `annee_2` index, which is probably why it is not using it.

Try adding `id_t3` to the end of that index on table `t2`:

```
(annee_t2,mois_t2,date_t2,id_t3)
```

This should permit the optimize to use that index.

Run the query again (twice, to populate the buffer cache, report only the 2nd result) and if it doesn't improve sufficiently, post the new EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you for taking time to answer me.
I'll add id_t3 to table t2 indexes and will publish EXPLAIN result.

Comment: I just added id_t3 to the indexes and the execution time was 201 sec for the first execution and 0 sec when cached!
Thanks a lot for your help, unfortunatly I can't thumb up your answer (I have less than 15 rep...)

I have another question btw, do I need to have indexes for columns that are already primary keys?
I suppose that if my tables was well made, with foreign keys I wouldn't have had this problem...
Thank you for your time, you made my day!

Comment: @TahaLeFoulek A primary key is an index, so you don't need to add additional indexes for them. Also, I think you should be able to at least accept my answer with your low rep. Look for the little check mark just below the upvote/downvote buttons, and click it to accept my answer. Glad I could help you!

Comment: I can't upvote, when I click on it, it says this :
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @TahaLeFoulek That's the upvote button. There should be a checkmark option just below the downvote button. Accepting an answer is different than upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

- The `GROUP BY` is probably improper since it does not include the t3 columns that are not aggergated.
- Do you really want 2 years plus 1 day?  Perhaps use this:

  ```
      t2.date_t2  >=  "2017-05-01"
  AND t2.date_t2   <  "2017-05-01" + INTERVAL 2 YEAR
  ```
- Do not mix datatypes when `JOINing` -- `ON t1.id_t4 = t4.ean_t4`:

  ```
  ean_t4 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  id_t4 bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  ```

(There may be other issues, but these should help.)